# Computer Vision Application on website

Tags: computer-vision

I want to create a website where a user can see how some Computer Vision algorithm or application wotks. For example, user uploads or gives a link to his image and clicks "RGB Decomposition", the result is 3 pictures: Red, Green and Blue channels of the original image.
Please, advise how to create it? I mean what technologies I should use. Web hosting or cloud computing service, etc.?

Comment: Thank you fro minusing the post. I don't even know where to search.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is too broad for SO. I have to say though that you cannot find a lot of places where you can ask that question. To answer it, depending on how advanced the algorithms you want to implement are, I would suggest to create a Rails site that implements those algorithms either in-page in Javascript or server-side in Ruby. If you have something computation-heavy (and depending on traffic), you might want to use C++ libraries, like OpenCV, wrapped in Ruby. AWS would be the best choice there, especially if you need GPU.

Comment: Thank you! That's the answer I want to hear. I wanted to implement algorithms in pure C++ and if need OpenCV don't want to use it a lot. Why don't use C++ as a server-side language. And one more question: do I need AWS or only hosting? Is there enough power for real-time exrcution of applications on website?

Comment: You can use any hosting you're familiar with, and the power depends on how many users you have vs how much you pay for servers. Why do you need real-time? Isn't it OK if the user waits for a few seconds? (see Wolfram Alpha as en example) C++ is not used as a Web programming language, so you will need some Ruby/Python/Java wrapper depending on what you know. PS: your question together with others prompted me to create http://computervisiondev.com/ (still not complete), you can join if you feel like it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've joined your project. Real-time - I used the wrong word. It's only must be fast and user doesn't need to download execution file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenCV combined with Python is a good option. Google for PyImageSearch and you will find some valuable resources by Adrian Rosebrock.

Comment: Thank you, I know this website and I have found an article about OpenCV + Python with Django web application solution by Adrian but I also want to know about pure C++ computer vision apps.

Comment: To mention a working example, I normally write C++ computer vision apps at my day job.These are wrapped in Ruby by colleagues who are familiar with web programming. We use both our own web servers and Amazon AWS, for hosting. With AWS, it is easy to adjust the server specs to match the workload. As @aledalgrande mentions, GPU can be used if needed.